# Proving $\mathbb Z[i]$ is euclidean domain .

Tags: number-theory, functions, complex-numbers

From the definition of [euclidean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Definition) domain , one has to select euclidean function .

Let  $\mathbb Z[i]=\{a+bi | a,b\in \mathbb Z,i=\sqrt{-1}\}$

We have to select an euclidean function $f$ , such that

$f$ is from $\mathbb Z[i]-\{0\}$ to $\mathbb N$

my doubt is how to select a good $f$ in-order to prove $\mathbb Z[i]$ is euclidean domain .

Is there any unique method to select or guess euclidean function ?

Are there multiple such $f$'s(euclidean function) to prove $\mathbb Z[i]$  is euclidean domain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the euclide norm $N(a+bi)=a^2+b^2$ and show that it is actually satisfies your needs

Comment: How can i guess that $f(a+ib)=a^2+b^2$?

Comment: think on the euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: Yeah , it is satisfying . Is $f(a+ib)=a^2+b^2$ unique ? I mean is there any other $f$ that satisfies too ?

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is called *evaluation* and it's a function
$$
f:\mathbb Z[i]\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb N
$$
which has to satisfy to the following properties:

$$
\bullet\;\; f(a)\le f(ab)\;\; \forall a,b\in\mathbb Z[i]\setminus\{0\}
$$
$$
\bullet\;\;\forall a,b\in\mathbb Z[i], b\neq0,\;\;\exists\; q,r\in\mathbb Z[i]\\\mbox{s.t.}\\
a=bq+r,\;\;r=0\;\;\mbox{or}\;\;f(r)<f(b)\;\;.
$$
The above are the properties to check in order to choose a good function.

The norm $f(a+ib):=a^2+b^2$ verify easily the above properties, hence it's a good choice.